# reverse proxy being blocked

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a case like this: my domain called zzzz.com is forwarded to xxxx.com, but I get an error message from Cloudflare, "403 Forbidden cloudflare". The error comes from xxxx.com. Here is my definition

```
location / {
proxy_cookie_domain https://www.xxxx.com https://www.zzzz.com;
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
proxy_set_header Host xxxx.com;
proxy_pass https://xxxx.com;
proxy_redirect https://xxxx.com https://zzzz.com;
subs_filter_types text/css text/javascript application/javascript;
subs_filter "https://(.*).xxxx.com/(.*)" "https://zzzz.com/$1/$2" gi;
subs_filter "https://xxxx.com" "https://zzzz.com" gi;
subs_filter "https://www.xxxx.com" "https://zzzz.com" gi;
subs_filter "www.xxxx.com" "zzzz.com" gi;
subs_filter "xxxx.com" "zzzz.com" gi;
}
```

what am I doing wrong? Why is cloudflare blocking me?

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it:

```
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
proxy_ssl_name $proxy_host;
```

Comment: I have the same exact problem and your solution does not make it work. CF blocks me.